# Parameter count mismatch when trying to update across threads

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to follow this example from MSDN:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1hetckb.aspx

I think i'm doing everything they did but i keep getting this error: Parameter count mismatch

Here is my code:

Form1:

```
 namespace ETL
 {
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
       private Thread myThread;
       public delegate void delegatePrintoutProcess(string myString);
       public delegatePrintoutProcess myDelegate2;
  ...

    private void startParseToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myDelegate2 = new delegatePrintoutProcess(updatePrintoutMethod);
        myThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadFunction));
        myThread.Start();  
    }
    public void updatePrintoutMethod(string text)
    {

       // this.richTextBox1.Text = text;
    }
    private void ThreadFunction()
    {
        parseFile myThreadClassObject = new parseFile(this);
        myThreadClassObject.getFilePath = filePath;
        myThreadClassObject.Run();


    }
}
```

parseFile class:

```
 namespace ETL
 {
    public class parseFile
    {
        Form1 myFormControl1;
    public parseFile(Form1 myForm)
    {
        //get a handle on the main form
        myFormControl1 = myForm;
    }
    String myString;
    public void Run()
    {

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            myString = "Step number " + i.ToString() + " executed";
            Thread.Sleep(400);
            // Execute the specified delegate on the thread that owns
            // 'myFormControl1' control's underlying window handle with
            // the specified list of arguments.
            myFormControl1.Invoke(myFormControl1.myDelegate,
                                   new Object[] { myString }); //error here
        }
    }
  }
```

I'm pretty sure i've followed the provided example, so not sure what is going on.

Thanks
jason

Comment: Probably, missing arguments in your delegate method. Look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guess (as no code to prove) - type of `myDelegate` is "function with 0 or 2 arguments", unlike `myDelegate2` that you probably wanted to call.

Comment: Thanks you for your response.  What do you mean by "No code to prove"?